# Calculate $\int_D x^2 dxdydz$ for $D$ an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $D$ be the ellipsoid $$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 \leq 1.$$
>   Compute $\int_D x^2 dx dy dz$.

Map to the unit ball by $\varphi: (x,y,z) \mapsto (x/a, y/b, z/c)$. Now $$\int_D \frac{1}{abc}x^2 dxdydz = \int_B (ax')^2dx'dy'dz'\\ \implies \int_D x^2 dx dy dz = abc \int_B a^2(x')^2 dx'dy'dz' \\=a^3bc\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \rho^2 \cos^2\varphi \rho^2 \sin\varphi d\rho d\theta d\varphi \\ = \frac{4a^3bc\pi}{15}.$$

Comment: But you're not doing volume; you're doing second moments. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Good, so I need not be worried. Does it seem right at first glance? I'd check with Wolfram, but I don't know how to enter this...

Comment: No, your spherical coordinates are not right, and you're missing the standard Jacobian. Plus $\Delta$ is a typo. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Does that look better now? I mapped $$(x,y,z) \mapsto (\rho \cos\varphi, \rho\sin\varphi\cos\theta, \rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta),$$ which I think is not orthodox, but it may simplify the integration.

Comment: Looks better, Eric. I would stick with standard coordinates but instead say that we get, by symmetry, the same integral with $z^2$. Indeed, you make the integral even easier if you use $(x^2+y^2+z^2)/3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Ted Shifrin's suggestion: 
$$ \begin{split}\int_B (x')^2dx'dy'dz'  & = \frac13\int_B ((x')^2 +(y')^2+(z')^2)\,dx'dy'dz'
\\ &= \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \rho^2 (4\pi \rho^2) \,d\rho = \frac{4\pi}{15} \end{split}$$
confirming the computation. The second step is integration over a sphere of radius $\rho$, which has the area $4\pi \rho^2$.